# Code to add a class when a field is empty or between certain times. As it spans over days it's difficult to work out

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out a way to add classes, when a field is empty, when a time range is open, when a time range is within 2 hours of closing time, when a time range is within 1 hour of closing time, and when a time range shows when something is closed.

I know what I want to do but can't figure out the logic as sometimes the time range spans across days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I just want to type in when a place is closed and have the code add one of 4 classes.
gray: an empty field
maybe-open: not withing the range submitted
closed: withing the range submitted
yellow: 2 hours before the range
orange: 1 hour before the range

Here is my code so far.

The range will look like this: 9pm - 10:30am

```
function custom_post_class($classes, $class, $post_id) {
    // Retrieve closing hours from field
    $closing_hours = get_field('field_65dfbc30e1727', $post_id); // Adjust field key as per your setup
    
    // If closing hours are empty, add 'gray' class to all items and return
    if (empty($closing_hours)) {
        $classes[] = 'gray';
        return $classes;
    }

    // Get current time in desired format
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
    $current_time = strtotime(date('H:i'));

    // Parse closing hours into start and end times
    $times = explode(' - ', $closing_hours);
    $closing_start_time = strtotime($times[0]);
    $closing_end_time = strtotime($times[1]);

    /*// Check if the closing time is on the next day
    if ($closing_start_time > $closing_end_time) {
        // Adjust closing end time to be on the next day
        $closing_end_time = strtotime('+1 day', $closing_end_time);
    }*/

    // Check if the current time is within open hours
    if ($current_time < $closing_start_time || $current_time > $closing_end_time) { 
        // Add 'closed' class if the current time is outside of the closing hours range
        $classes[] = 'maybe-open';
    
    /*} elseif (($current_time >= $closing_start_time && $current_time <= strtotime('23:59', $closing_end_time)) ||
               ($current_time >= strtotime('00:00', $closing_start_time) && $current_time <= $closing_end_time)) {*/
                   
    } else {                
        // Add 'maybe-open' class if the shop might be open
        $classes[] = 'closed';
    }

    // Calculate time differences
    $time_diff_current = $closing_end_time - $current_time; // Difference between closing time and current time

    // Add 'yellow' class if the current time is within 2 hours of the range
    if ($time_diff_current <= 7200 && $time_diff_current > 3600 && !in_array('closed', $classes)) {
       $classes[] = 'yellow';
    }

    // Add 'orange' class if the current time is within an hour of the range
    if ($time_diff_current <= 3600 && $time_diff_current > 0 && !in_array('closed', $classes)) {
        $classes[] = 'orange';
    }

    // Add 'closed' class if the current time is exactly at the closing time
    if ($time_diff_current == 0) {
        $classes[] = 'closed';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'custom_post_class', 10, 3);

?>
```

As it's a bit complicated I'm using the questions to go through the logic.

1. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 9pm is the class "closed"?
2. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 11pm is the class "yellow"?
3. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 12am is the class "orange"?
4. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 1am is the class "maybe-open"?
5. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 1pm to 2pm is the class "maybe-open"?
6. If the field is empty is the class "gray"?
7. If the current time is 10:01pm and the closing time is 10am to 3pm, the same as question 5, the class must be "maybe-open", right?

I tried using ChatGTP as well but the code seems to be too difficult for it. And it keeps showing me broken code or repeating to show me code that works in the morning but not at night for some reason.

---

If the time is 3:48pm the class should be "closed" but it is showing as "maybe-open" when the closing time is 2pm to 10:30am. I'm not sure why though.

03:48 PM (1709880480) Current Time

02:00 PM (1709874000) Closed - Start Time

10:30 AM (1709861400) Closed - End Time